# I am using Xcode 7 and Swift, and my control drag action is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using Xcode 7 and when I am using control drag to make an action with my `UITextView` to the ViewController.swift file, only the blue line shows up, but no line underneath the ViewController.swift file in which I can choose for an Outlet or Action.

Comment: Make sure that your storyboard viewcontroller has the class mentioned in `YourNameViewController.Swift`

Comment: @Fennec thanks! It works now. I can't thank you enough for this. I have been looking for so many solutions and now I've finally gotten one that I have understood!

Comment: I have added this comment as an answer for someone else having the same issue. Feel free to upvote if you like.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These type of issues come into play when you try to connect the `ViewController` to a class that has a different class mentioned in the `Identity Inspector` of the storyboard. Make sure your view controller has the same class name mentioned in the storyboard to which you are trying to connect.

As shown in the image, make sure the class name is correct to which you are trying to connect.

[image]

Thank You!